# DevExpress Charts Question

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

Is it possible to create chart (as shown on screenshot) in DevExpress Chart control?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: I just need answer if this is possible to create such chart. I'm not asking for actual code solution

Answer (score 0):

I have developed something similiar, already. I learned that it is better to use XtraGrid instead of the chart, as pattern matrix. The I used CustomCell drawing feature to draw colored bars according values in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid DevExpress charts if you are rendering anything more than 100 data points. At least in v14 and v15, the charting controls are very, very slow compared to most things out there. Every time it redraws, you have to wait seconds for it to redraw.

This does not detract from how awesome the rest of DevExpress is (its my library of choice for everything else).

Answer (score 0):

I think a different component (*Pivot Table*) is a more suitable solution here.

For instance, DevExpress PivotGridControl supports in-place editors such as Progress Bar (see the [following example](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5899/controls-and-libraries/pivot-grid/examples/data-editing/how-to-assign-an-in-place-editor-to-a-data-field's-cells)).

In addition, you can hide cells with zero values by handling the [CustomCellDisplayText](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridControl.CustomCellDisplayText) event and setting the *e.DisplayText* property to an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is YES, it is possible